# How to make MP3 file play in the background of HTML/CSS/JS page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Would like to have an MP3 track play in the background immediately after a HTML/CSS/JavaScript page is loaded.

So far, only able to have a player with controls at the bottom of the page:

Bottom of webpage

[image]

using the following code:

```html
 <audio id="bg_music" class="audio" controls loop>
                <source src="audio/silent-night.mp3"
                    type="audio/mp3">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
```

Would like to find a way to have the MP3 file play automatically after the browser (Chrome) loads the webpage.

Thanks,
Benjamin

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Comment: According to the article, it seems that my .js file needs to be modified, but am not sure where to start.
@Quentin  would you be able to assist?
<https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-SQOnXkd125RBlGKrlhW_51kJu2G8aEn?usp=sharing>

Comment: According to the article, what you want is impossible.

Comment: hi @Quentin 
One example would be this page <https://quantumgame.io/level/1>, which was developed using Vue.js <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js>

Answer (score -2):

You need to add an attributed `autoplay`, and it will be done. You may additionaly provide value `autoplay=true` or `autoplay=false`, but still if you don't give it, it will automatically consider it to be true if you just add the attribute.

```html
<audio id="bg_music" class="audio" autoplay controls loop>
  <source src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: This [usually will not work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#Autoplay_and_autoplay_blocking) on modern browsrs.

Comment: [`false` is not a valid value for the `autoplay` attribute.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute)

Comment: thank you @Quentin for the link to the Developer article.

Comment: thank you @Deadpool for the code snippet. Unfortunately, it still does not work:
<http://waggish-wish.surge.sh/>